# C++ Implementing an attack class in a game

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

For learning and fun I've decided to create a mini-version of Starcraft 2 using classes.  I've created a ProtossUnit base class and two derived classes Zealot and Stalker.  Now I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement an attack (damage another unit).

I've included a function in the ProtossUnit base class, but maybe there's a more elegant/better way such as creating a Class Attack.  I believe this would allow me more customization with the attacks (including upgrades/rate of attack etc.).  I was thinking of giving the inheritance of the Attack class to the derived classes, since they hold the damage stats?

Any help appreciated.

```
class ProtossUnit {
protected:
    int psishield, health, armor;
    int mineralcost, gascost;   
public:
    int getHealth() { return health; }
    int getPsiShield() { return psishield; }
    int getArmor() { return armor; }
};

class Zealot : public ProtossUnit {
public:
    string attacktype;
    int damage, attackspeed;
    Zealot() {
        attacktype = "Psi Blades";
        psishield = 50;
        health = 100;
        damage = 8 * 2;
        attackspeed = 1.2;
        mineralcost = 100;
        gascost = 0;
    }
};

class Stalker : public ProtossUnit {
public:
    string attacktype;
    int damage, attackspeed;
    Stalker() {
        attacktype = "Ranged";
        psishield = 80;
        health = 80;
        damage = 10;
        attackspeed = 1.44;
        mineralcost = 125;
        gascost = 50;           
    } 
};

class Attack {
private:
    string attackName;
    int damage, attackspeed;
public:
    Attack(string aName, int dmg, int aspeed) {
        attackName = aName;
        damage = dmg;
        attackspeed = aspeed;
    }

};
```

Comment: An initialization list should be preferred to setting each variable in the constructor body.  For POD types (as you have) it doesn't actually matter, but for other types it avoids a call to their default constructor (assuming they have one and, if not, you *have* to use an initialization list.  Also if you have a `const` member variable).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's important to realize there are many possible designs.  In my head, I'd think that a Unit would have the ability (method) to attack another unit, so maybe it takes the target as some parameter.  Then depending on the attack, you can do some random stuff (literally, generate probabilistic results) and adjust with the health (or w.e) of the target unit.  This is where an Attack class may come into play: if a unit has a lot of different attacks, or different units share attacks, maybe a reusable attack class with some general behavior would be helpful.  There is no wrong answer.